# Cannot enable Rasberry Pi camera

Tags: camera, raspicam, raspi-config

Whenever I try uploading a code to run my camera it says camera not enabled , therefore I activated my camera from the rasberrypi configurator which did not work as well , also updated camera using sudo apt get-upgrade / update . After all those steps the camera still seeems to not be seen as enabled from the Raspberry Pi I also  tried the command sudo apt raspi-config and the option of enabling the camera was not there. I am truly out of options.

Does anyone have a solution to this or know what might be the problem ?
Thank you

Comment: To get an answer, you'll have to provide more details on exactly what you did at each step. Likely some detail is wrong, but we won't be able to guess which one given this description.

Comment: Check the ribbon cable is the correct way around and isn't damaged, then check them again. They have to be say in perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The command line command is **not**:

```
sudo apt raspi-config
```

it is:

`sudo raspi-config`.

The option to enable the camera is under interfacing options.

You should also reboot after enabling the camera.